# Portable application on usb updating registry

Tags: c#, registry, portable-executable, portable-applications

I want to write a portable application which resides on a USB. When usb attached to pc, the application automatically starts and it may set entry to registry. I want to remove these entries when USB drive removed from the PC. Is it possible to do this?

I know that I can use autorun on my USB drive to start my application, but is there any way that I inform my application that USB needs to be removed, so it can clear the registry?

I am using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to P/Invoke a Win32 API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480%28VS.85%29.aspx.

That should give you the events you need for when it is being unplugged.

Comment: Based on this answer I found the following sites usefull:  If using WinForm: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program  in wpf: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/983dc1ee-6208-4036-903f-3fd5674a1efb/